# Why can not get alert when on html table row click?

Tags: javascript

I have this html table:

```
<table class="table" id="requestTable">
  <thead class="text-primary">
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>موضوع درخواست</th>
    <th>نوع درخواست</th>
    <th>نام رابط شرکت</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>@item.Id</td>
      <td>@item.subjects</td>
      <td>@item.requesttype</td>
      <td>@item.interfacename</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and write this jquery code:

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#requestTable tr').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#requestTable tr").click(function() {
      alert("You clicked my <td>!" + $(this).html() + 
            "My TR is:" + $(this).parent("tr").html());
      //get <td> element values here!!??
    });
  });​
</script>
```

but when i try to click on the row, don't get any alert.

Comment: You are handling `tr` element of table (`$("#requestTable tr").click`) not `td` element

Comment: @YasharAliabasi is correct, you are handling a `tr` click, then trying to find a parent `tr` which will, obviously, not exist. The parent of a `tr` should be `tbody` or `thead` in your instance. On a side note you should learn how to use `console.log` for debugging instead of `alert`

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: @Sunny my browser is chrome

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Use your network tab in your browser tools to make sure all your resources have loaded.

Comment: @JonP please wait...

Comment: @JonP yes my friend all resource loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that jquery has been loaded properly? My guess is that jquery can not be resolved using the ~/ or does not exist at that location

This fiddle seems to alert properly.
https://jsfiddle.net/o5aj1nww/

Try replacing your script tag with this

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had made some changes in your code.

**Changes:**

1. Jquery Reference
2. Click event

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#requestTable tr').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#requestTable tr td").click(function () {
            alert("You clicked my <td>! " + $(this).html() +
                  " My TR is:" + jQuery(this).closest('tr').text());

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table class="table" id="requestTable">
            <thead class="text-primary">
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Request Type</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="row">
                    <td>@item.Id</td>
                    <td>@item.subjects</td>
                    <td>@item.requesttype</td>
                    <td>@item.interfacename</td>
                </tr>
                  <tr class="row">
                    <td>@item.Id 1</td>
                    <td>@item.subjects 1</td>
                    <td>@item.requesttype 1</td>
                    <td>@item.interfacename 1</td>
                </tr>
                  <tr class="row">
                    <td>@item.Id 2</td>
                    <td>@item.subjects 2</td>
                    <td>@item.requesttype 2</td>
                    <td>@item.interfacename 2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Hope this will work for you. Please let me know if you still face any issue. I will try to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#request table tr').find('tr').click( function(){
    var row = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    alert("You clicked my <td>!" + $(this).html() + 
    "My TR is:" + $(this).parent("tr").html());
  });
</script>
```